How to best use Micro-Cap?
Several users of this site recommended I switch to Micro-Cap for simulation.  I'm having trouble with their schematic capture:
First, the symbols are very small compared to the text.  Is there a way to set the default sizes to match?

I'm also unclear how to wire components. I'm used to doing this as I place them, but it seems I need to first place them, then hit Ctrl-W to switch to wire mode, and then wire them.  Is that correct?
Finally, I am trying to make a DC Square Wave, but struggling how to set it.  I want 7 MHz, 0V OFF, 6V ON, 50% duty cycle.  I'm not sure how to set the P vals for that.  Ideally, I'd like the basic info to appear on the schematic.

Like any software there's a bit of a learning curve but, I can assure you that you won't regret this move.

Link to microcap v12, read rm12.pdf and ug12.pdf files.
Click on component, change "Fonts" ...
For wiring, click on "orthogonal wire" or "Diagonal wire" mode.
For Square Wave generator, click on "Components", "Analog Primitives", "Waveform source", "Pulse wave", then "Square".
Then set the variables.
Add in the schematic, these define without the quotes.
".define fr 7Meg" and ".define duty 0.5".


"Click on component, change "Fonts" ..."  This works component by component, but becomes very tedious.  It seems that Micro Cap sets the default font size to component size based on some computer setting - I installed Micro Cap on a different computer (that I can't normally use) and the ratio was fine.  But, on my computer, the components are so small compared to fonts as to be almost unusable.

"Add in the schematic - ".define fr 7Meg" and ".define duty 0.5".  Where do I add that? With what tool? Are those global variables that apply to the whole circuit? Also, if P3 is ON time and P4 off time, I don't think your calculations will be correct (unless it's 50% duty).  Finally, when rise time is important, don't I need to have some rise time - isn't that what P1 and P4 are for?
